# Openpyxl - Reading an intersecting column while you're iter_rows'ing

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am not great at Python, to be sure. I've done a ton of beginner tutorials but never really worked on anything intermediate. I have searched the site and asked this question on other sites to no avail. I am trying to half-automate something for my job.

Imagine an excel spreadsheet with the following column headings:

Date | A-D | 1-3 | A1_absent | A1_late | A2_absent | A2_late ->

In every row, for each combination of A-D and 1-3, there are exactly and only two columns in which one name or several names **could** appear. All others will be blank. Guaranteed. Of the two could-be-filled cells, one does not require the other. Both could be filled. Neither could be filled (rare and ignorable). The first but not the second and vice versa. Given the combos, this equates to an f-ton of columns for each row that are really annoying to go through by hand. Example row:

8/23 | A | 2 | [blank] | [blank] | Joe Shmo | Sue Doo | [blank] | [blank] | -> into eternity

But, really central to my problem, it could also be:

8/23 | A | 2 | [blank] | [blank] | **[blank]** | Sue Doo | [blank] | [blank] | -> into eternity

I can't count on the first find being absent. I am trying to write a python script to go through this excel file and produce this:

```
Date
A-D
1-3
Absent: [Names]
Late: [Names]
```

I'm using prints for testing in my code. I may choose to do something else with this when I get it right. The first three items from above are cake. They're straight-forward, fixed references. For the next two, late/absence and names, I have to search through blanks. I can find the filled names and display them, but I cannot figure out how to read the title column that intersects that filled name. I need this because I cannot count on the first find to be one of the two. Once this is solved, I could "absent" in [reference] the cell and that would be that. I suspect I need another iterator somewhere..maybe a count in the current iterator to reference..but my tests with this have gone poorly so far. Maybe I need an entirely different approach, which I'm open to.

Here's the code:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook


def blankpop():
    workbook = load_workbook(filename="test.xlsx")
    sheet = workbook.active
    for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=3):
        print(str(row[0].value)[5:10]) #date formatting
        print(row[1].value)
        print(row[2].value)

        for item in row[3:]:
            if item.value == "":
                pass
            else:
                print(str(item.value))
                print("----") #separating filled cells for testing purposes

        print("/n") #separating rows
```

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Given no one ever responded, I went back to work. The solution here has to do with utilizing iter_rows **without** using `values_only=True`. This will return row objects with cell objects in them. For loop to get to the cell objects, and it is at this point you can reference the cell's column with `cell.column`. With the problem I was solving, the row was absolute, so at this point, it's about using openpyxl's `cell()` function to reference an absolute location. The call is `sheet.cell(row=x, column=x)`.

Here's my solution:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook


def blankpop():

    workbook = load_workbook(filename="9-18.xlsx")
    sheet = workbook.active

    for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=3):
        print(str(row[0].value)[5:10]) #date formatting
        print(row[1].value)
        print(row[2].value)

        for item in row[3:]:
            if item.value == "":
                pass
            else:
                print(sheet.cell(row=1, column=item.column).value)
                print(str(item.value))

        print("\n")
```